# Error 404 when accessing rest resource

Tags: java, resteasy

I am having trouble with this simple RestEasy service:

```
@Path("/")
public interface UserService {

    @POST
    @Path("/add")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    Response add(User user);

    @POST
    @Path("/update")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    Response update(User user);

    @GET
    @Path("/get/{id}")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    Response get(@PathParam("id") long id);

    @GET
    @Path("/getAll")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    Response getAll();

}
```

Basically, the above code works, however when I change the `@Path("/")` to `@Path("/user")` and access the resource like:

```
http://localhost:8080/user/add
```

it throws error `404`. Unlike from the original `http://localhost:8080/UserService/add` that works.

Am I missing something in the code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you could try

```
http://localhost:8080/UserService/user/add
```

for @Path(/user)

Comment: This worked, but is there any way to defined the PATH without having the interface name, like UserService in the PATH, i mean like just /user/add ?

Comment: How do you expose your service ? Inside a webapp via the resteasy servlet ? How it is declare in your web.xml ?